# find $A_0$, $x_0$ such that the Gauss integration formula $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)|x| \,dx\, \approx$ $A_0 f(x_0)$ will be with maximum accuracy degree

Tags: numerical-methods, gaussian-integral

Hint: the formula will calculate the true value integrals of the form $\int_{-1}^{1} x^n |x| \,dx$ for all $n=0,1,...k$
such that $k$ is the accuracy degree.

How can I approach this?

An easy guess : $k=0$,$A_0 =1$  and $x_0 = 0$.

However, I don't know if the maximum value for $k$ is 0.

Comment: Your easy guess has $k=1$ in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $n$ yield an equation
$$
\int_{-1}^1 x^n |x| dx = A_0 x_0^n.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\int_{-1}^1 x^n |x| dx = \begin{cases}
\frac{2}{n+2}, &n \text{ is even}\\
0, &n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

So we have the following system of nonlinear equations for $A_0$ and $x_0$:
$$
1 = A_0, \quad n = 0\\
0 = A_0 x_0, \quad n = 1\\
\vdots\\
\int_{-1}^1 x^k |x| dx = A_0 x_0^k, \quad n = k.
$$
The first two equations immediately require $A_0 = 1, x_0 = 0$. If we truncate system at $n = 1$ then $A_0 = 1, x_0 = 0$ will be the solution. So $k$ is at least 1.

Let's check that $k$ cannot be greater than 1. If $k > 1$ then for $n = 2 \leq k$ the integration should be exact:
$$
\frac{2}{4} = A_0 x_0^2.
$$
But it is not true, so $k$ cannot be greater than $1$.